# How do you use inspectdb in Django?

Tags: django

I am just starting with Django, and I would like to make an app that uses my existing sqlite db.

I read the docs and I found that you can create models from a db, using inspectdb; altho I can't find an example of how you use that command, on an existing db.

I copied the db file inside the directory of my project, ran the command and I see that a sqlite3 file is created in my directory project.
Altho the file has nothing to do with the database that I made. I tried to pass the db name to the inspectdb command but it says that it doesn't accept parameters.

So how can I actually tell the command to use my db to create the model for my app?

There must be some obvious step that I am missing...this is what I did:

```
-created the project
-created the app
-copied my db inside the project folder
-ran inspectdb
```

But I see the model empty, and a new db called `db.sqlite3` created

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer: there is a variable that has to be set, to define which one is the db that the application will use. the default is set to "db.sqlite3", which explain why I am getting this behavior.

Once you modify the name with the database that I already made, the command run without issues.

Not sure if it is just me getting stomped, but this info about the name that has to be changed was not mentioned anywhere...

Thanks